# How to make latexindent align columns in nested environments?

Tags: formatting, indentation, latexindent

The following MWE is the result of running `latexindent` with default settings:

```
\documentclass[border=1in, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%

\begin{document}
First, we obtain the eigenvalues:
\begin{align*}
    \abs*{
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            4 - \lambda & -1 & -1\\
            1 & 2 - \lambda & - 1\\
            1 & -1 & 2 - \lambda
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    } & = (4 - \lambda) \abs*{
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            2 - \lambda & -1\\
            -1 & 2 - \lambda
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    } + \abs*{
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            1 & - 1\\
            1 & 2 - \lambda
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    } - \abs*{
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            1 & 2 - \lambda\\
            1 & -1
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    }                                                                               \\
      & = (4 - \lambda)(\lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + 3) + (-\lambda + 3) + (3 - \lambda) \\
      & = -\lambda^3 + 8 \lambda^2 - 21 \lambda + 18                                \\
      & = -(\lambda - 2)(\lambda - 3)^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, only the alignment symbols of the `align` environment were aligned in the code after running `latexindent`. The alignment symbols within the `bNiceMatrix` environments (i.e., the first and second ones) were ignored. Is there a way to make them aligned in the code as well?

PDF output for reference:
[image: minimal working example]

**EDIT:** Note that I included the PDF output to give more context to the MWE, but my question is about code formatting using `latexindent`, not document layout. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, what you like to have intended? I don't see anything that are ignored.

Comment: In the first ```bNiceMatrix``` environment, I would like for the ampersands to be aligned as well. Right now, they are left unaligned, unlike the ampersands in the "parent" ```align``` environment.

Comment: What do you call the ampersands??? `&` doesn't have to appear in the .pdf.

Comment: `&` delimits columns of the matrix.  The *contents* of those columns are center aligned.  Are you asking for column contents to instead be right- or left-aligned?

Comment: I may have miscommunicated.

No, I do not intend to change the alignment of the contents of the matrices in the PDF, nor do I intend to make the ```&``` symbols appear in the PDF. My intention is for the formatting of the *code* to be aligned at the ```&``` delimiters within the ```bNiceMatrix``` environments using ```latexindent```. Observe the ```align``` environment. Notice that the ```&``` and ```\\``` symbols are aligned per equality. I would like that behavior to be exhibited in the ```bNiceMatrix``` environments as well, code-format-wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to tell `latexindent.pl` to look for alignment delimiters in the `bNiceMatrix`, as detailed in https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html#lst-aligndelims-advanced

Starting with your `.tex` file, then we employ the following YAML file, say `john.yaml`:

```yaml
lookForAlignDelims:
   bNiceMatrix: 1
```

and then we run

```
latexindent.pl -l john.yaml mwe.tex
```

The output is as follows:

```tex
\documentclass[border=1in, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%

\begin{document}
First, we obtain the eigenvalues:
\begin{align*}
    \abs*{
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            4 - \lambda & -1          & -1          \\
            1           & 2 - \lambda & - 1         \\
            1           & -1          & 2 - \lambda
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    } & = (4 - \lambda) \abs*{
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            2 - \lambda & -1          \\
            -1          & 2 - \lambda
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    } + \abs*{
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            1 & - 1         \\
            1 & 2 - \lambda
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    } - \abs*{
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            1 & 2 - \lambda \\
            1 & -1
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    }                                                                               \\
      & = (4 - \lambda)(\lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + 3) + (-\lambda + 3) + (3 - \lambda) \\
      & = -\lambda^3 + 8 \lambda^2 - 21 \lambda + 18                                \\
      & = -(\lambda - 2)(\lambda - 3)^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You can achieve the same result without having to create a YAML file, by using the `-y` switch as in the following:

```bash
latexindent.pl -y lookForAlignDelims:bNiceMatrix:1 mwe.tex
```

### about nesting alignment

The specific question about nested alignment and the customisation thereof is a known issue; see https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-conclusions-know-limitations.html for example. I hope to be able to address this at some point.

Comment: Perhaps the environments from the `nicematrix` package should be added to `defaultSettings.yaml`....? feedback at https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl welcome

Comment: As of V3.8.3, latexindent looks for these environments by default, no local config necessary :)  November 2020