# latexindent add tblr (tabularray) environment as tabular for aligning at &

Tags: tabularray, latexindent

I wanted to know if there is a way to let `latexindent` know that `tblr` is a `tabular` environment by the package `tabularray` which means that the content should be aligned at `&`.

I could only manage to get the correct indent and alignment by changing the `tblr` environment to a `tabular` environment temporarily and then after `latexindent` ran over the  tabular I changed it back to `tblr`.

Example how it should look like.
[image]

More examples (with working `tabular` NOT `tblr`):

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

`Latexindent` can do the alignment for `tabular` and I would like to know how I can configure or add `tblr` to be aligned at `&` the same as `tabular` works.

Comment: Sorry, your question is quite unclear. Please, provide an MWE, which reproduce your problem. BTW, all what can be done by `tabular` can be done with `tblr` too.

Comment: @Zarko This is not about the `tabular` or `tblr` but rather about `latexindent` which is perl script for indenting your latex document. There is no real MWE because the perl-script works on the `.tex`-file.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that your perl script is hard coded for `tabular`. You need to ask how to change it that be more versatile. What is benefit to use  `latextindent`?

Comment: @Zarko Well I am using `VS Codium` as an IDE for LaTeX and I have a shortcut to automatically use `latexindent`. It just indents the whole document to the standard indentation and is useful for alignment in e.g. `align` environments or `tabular`s. It is more of a convenience thing that I can press a shortcut and the document is ‚cleaned up‘ in the source code.

Comment: You could write an issue for `latexindent` to request support for the `tabularray` environments.

Comment: this may be a related question: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568637/how-to-make-latexindent-align-columns-in-nested-environments

Comment: The script is not hard coded for tabular, and is customisable via the yaml interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As of V3.16 this is default settings, so need for user configuration. You can still use the file below, it won't break anything but isn't necessary.*

We need to tell `latexindent.pl` to look for alignment delimiters in the `tblr`, as detailed in https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html#lst-aligndelims-advanced

We employ the following YAML file, say `martin.yaml`:

```yaml
lookForAlignDelims:
   tblr: 1
```

and then we run

```
latexindent.pl -l martin.yaml mwe.tex
```

All of this, and more including many examples, is detailed in the [documentation](https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: As of V3.16 this is default settings, so need for user configuration